# How to make the 'clickable hand' appear in an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built a sample HTML webpage recently, and when I hover the mouse pointer over a `<div>` element that makes a drop down menu come down on click, the pointer changes to a cursor, allowing me to highlight the text in the `<div>`.

The thing is, I don't want the mouse pointer to change to a cursor.(I don't want to be able to highlight the text either.) I want it to either remain the way it is or change to the 'clickable hand' pointer that comes up when the mouse pointer hovers over a link.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cursor can be changed using CSS `cursor` property.

```
cursor:pointer;
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

---

You can also prevent highlighting using the `user-select` property:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

---

For example:

```
div{
   cursor:pointer;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: The only complete answer.

Comment: Better answer worth the green tick

Comment: In lieu of the original question, Akshay, you gave the correct and complete answer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Set

```
cursor:pointer
```

on the div

like

```
div{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

and as kurt suggested you can use

```
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
```

to remove the highlight

Comment: I think the text remains highlight-able, though, right?

Comment: @Akshay I can highlight that text

Comment: @user3154108 Try now if you are using chrome http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/fkjubs3k/1/

Comment: Please update your answer with the changes you've made in the Fiddle

Comment: @Anzeo Sure just  a minute

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```css
#div-id {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cursor:pointer;` in your css.

check here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp for al possibilities for the cursor property

Answer (score 0):

Set the role attribute to `button`:

```html
<div role="button"></div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role